# Failover Cluster Installation in SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server-2017

Can we install SQL Server failover cluster in SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition without WSFC?

I want to practice on Always-on and how it works, which is why I want to install SQL Server failover cluster, however I have not created the WSFC.

Is it possible?

Comment: I think you mean Availability Groups.

Comment: Clusterless AGs, [described here](https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/clusterless-availability-groups/). And [official docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15). Note that this configuration only supports read scale - you don't get any of the HA/failover benefits that would have been furnished by the underlying cluster.